# Expand/collapse option for Toolbar

Tags: notebooks, docked-cell

When creating a docked cell, the toolbar stays forever visible and somewhat "eats up" space. Since I do not use the different buttons all the time, is there a way to make the toolbar expand/collapse?

Comment: Making a collapsible `DynamicModule` for your content is the standard way. Or a button that toggles the `CellOpen` and `CellSize` options works too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to create a new screen environment, that is identical to the usual "Working" screen environment, except that it has the toolbar. For example:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[], 
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData[All, "Toolbar", StyleDefinitions->StyleData[All,"Working"]],
            DockedCells->Cell[BoxData["123"]],
            MenuCommandKey -> "u"
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

The above stylesheet toggles the docked cell when switching between the "Working" and "Toolbar" screen environments (i.e., `Format | ScreenEnvironment`menu item). I also included a `MenuCommandKey` option so that using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> turns on the docked cell. A similar shortcut could be added for the "Working" screen environment.

Here's an animation:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work. It is probably my fault since I am a beginner at this, but evaluating this in a notebook does not do anything?

Comment: @Patrick.B Does the animation help?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach, adding a `Button` to collapse the cell:

```
ddd = Cell[
 BoxData@ToBoxes@Pane["I am a big content", {Scaled[1], 50}, Alignment -> Center],
 CellFrameLabelMargins -> 0,
 CellFrameLabels -> {
   {None, None},
   {ButtonBox["",
     ButtonFunction :>
      Function[
       With[{pc = ParentCell@EvaluationCell[]},
        SetOptions[
         pc,
         If[CurrentValue[pc, CellSize] === 0,
          {
           CellSize -> Inherited,
           CellElementSpacings -> {},
           CellFrameMargins -> Inherited
           },
          {
           CellSize -> 0,
           CellElementSpacings -> {
             "CellMinHeight" -> 0
             },
           CellFrameMargins -> 0
           }
          ]
         ]
        ]
       ],
     ImageSize -> {Scaled[2], 15},
     Evaluator -> Automatic
     ],
    None
    }
   }
 ]
```

Then:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> ddd]
```

[image]

[image]

Doesn't survive saving, of course, but that could be done by having the `CellSize` depend on a [`TaggingRule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TaggingRules.html) via `` FrontEnd`CurrentValue `` and `` FEPrivate`If `` and then having the button only check and set that rule.

I do that for toolbars in my IDE:

[image]

[image]

that way they can persist across sessions

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner at this, so I am not sure how to work with your code. Evaluating it does what I want, but I don't know how I can add my already defined docked cells with this, since the above code overrides the current toolbar?

Comment: @Patrick.B simply add those options to the cell you already have or replace the BoxData with your cell content.